# How to fullscreen DetailView of UISplitViewController in Landscape

Tags: ipad, orientation, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a UISplitViewController with a common detailView (right side).

I add a button to detailView in landscape orientation, when the button is clicked, the **masterView(left side) will be hide** and **detailView will become fullscreen**. just like the behavior of the **Dropbox app for iPad**

Now, I can hide the masterView but cannot change detailView to fullscreen by just setting detailviewController.view's frame.

width of splitview's left side = 321,
and the detailviewController.view.frame is {{321,0}, {703, 748}} before changed.

If I change the detailview.frame by following code, there is **no change happened**.

```
self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 748);
```

And It will change position if I use following code, but **that's not fullscreen**.

```
self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 703, 748);
```

I found if I change the frame with a larger size (ex. 704) than its origin width, the position of the frame will not change.

How to make a detailview to become whole screen width under landscape orientation?
Any suggestion will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I see another possibility to use + transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion: method of UIView to exchange UISplitViewCintroller's view for other fullscreen UIView instance in UIWindow view

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution in the below link to create a custom splitview controller, you can tweak this to get the desired effect. I dont think it is possible to change the frame size of master and detail view of the normal UISplitViewController (I tried in iOS5, it didnt work).

[Custom SplitView](http://www.mindtreatstudios.com/our-projects/custom-uisplitviewcontroller-ios/)

-anoop

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the method `viewWillTransitionToSize`,this method will be called whenever our device orientation changes and in that the following will help you achieve what you want.

```
-(void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator{
    self.splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryHidden;
}
```

The `preferredDisplayMode` can be used to make the master View hide or show or overlay over the Detail View controller.